# ORACLE - Join definition table with data table

Tags: sql, oracle

Given the two table shown below, I need to retrieve for each station, the latest values from the `VAL_MINUTES` table

**N_STATION**

```
| CODE_STAS | NOM_STATION | RIVIERE_BASSIN | LAMBERT_X | LAMBERT_Y |
|-----------|-------------|----------------|-----------|-----------|
|      5634 | StationA    | RiverA         |        50 |        60 |
|      2113 | StationB    | RiverB         |        55 |        95 |
```

**VAL_MINUTES**

```
| CODE_MESURE |  DATE_VAL  | M_05 | M_10 | M_15 | M_20 | M_25 | M_30 |
|-------------|------------|------|------|------|------|------|------|
|      563484 | 22/11/2016 | 0.02 | 0.35 | 0.48 |  0.2 | 0.65 | 0.45 |
|      563484 | 23/11/2016 |  1.2 |  0.9 | 1.15 | 0.84 | 0.89 | 1.02 |
|      563484 | 23/11/2016 |  1.2 |  0.9 | 1.15 | 0.84 | 0.89 | 1.02 |
|      211374 | 22/11/2016 | 0.03 |  0.1 | 0.24 | 0.21 | 0.18 | 0.19 |
```

**RESULT EXPECTED**

```
| CODE_STAS |  DATE_VAL  | M_05 | M_10 | M_15 | M_20 | M_25 | M_30 | NOM_STATION | RIVIERE_BASSIN | LAMBERT_X | LAMBERT_Y |
|-----------|------------|------|------|------|------|------|------|-------------|----------------|-----------|-----------|
|      5634 | 23/11/2016 |  1.2 |  0.9 | 1.15 | 0.84 | 0.89 | 1.02 | StationA    | RiverA         |        50 |        60 |
|      2113 | 22/11/2016 | 0.03 |  0.1 | 0.24 | 0.21 | 0.18 | 0.19 | StationB    | RiverB         |        55 |        95 |
```

*NOTE*

- `SUBSTR(code_mesure,1,4) = code_stas`
- It is possible to have multiple times the same date. We should use `order by date_val desc` and take the first one
- As you can see with the `code_mesure 563484` there is the same line 2 times. It is a possible case. The latest (as seen above) will be used.

---

I tried the following query

```
SELECT  *
FROM    ( SELECT    code_mesure ,
                    date_val ,
                    m_05 ,
                    m_10 ,
                    m_15 ,
                    m_20 ,
                    m_25 ,
                    m_30 ,
                    RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY code_mesure ORDER BY date_val DESC ) AS rnk
          FROM      VAL_MINUTES
        ) x
        INNER JOIN N_STATION st ON SUBSTR(x.code_mesure, 1, 4) = st.CODE_STAS
WHERE   x.rnk = 1
```

But I get multiples times the same station because a station has a list of different code_mesure

```
|CODE_STAS |CODE_MESURE          |
|----------|---------------------|
|      1021|102148, 102159,102132|
```

*How can I get the expected result above ?*

Comment: try to use `partition by SUBSTR(x.code_mesure,1,4)` instead in the rank function, that should do the trick

Comment: @EmilHolub I still have multiple times the same station

Comment: Then the most recent date is not unique - you need to specify what to do in that case with your query - either add another column to your ordering or some other condition

Comment: @EmilHolub See the notes. When their is multiple times the same date I should take the first one when ordered desc. Unfortunately I cannot edit the database

Comment: What do you mean first one? If the dates are the same then the order which is first is **random** if you do not have some other form of ID. Then if you mean that you want to take a **random** row out of those having the same most current row then that is a different task.

Comment: @EmilHolub I just want to take the first one when I am using `order by date_val desc`. I know that it sounds weird...

Comment: @EmilHolub Actually I just saw that there is a date+hour inside `date_val`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bad idea to store a composed value (5634|84) in a single field. You should have two separate columns instead.

Anyway, you want to rank the data in table `val_minutes`. There can be ties and you want to pick a single record though. So use `ROW_NUMBER` (rather than `RANK` or `DENSE_RANK`) to give each record in a partition (i.e. within a `code_stas`) a number:

```
select 
  m.m_05, m.m_10, m.m_15, m.m_20, m.m_25, m.m_30, 
  s.nom_station, s.riviere_bassin, s.lambert_x, s.lambert_y
from n_station s
join
(
  select 
    substr(code_mesure,1,4) as code_stas,
    vm.*,
    row_number() over (partition by substr(code_mesure,1,4) order by date_val desc) as rnk
  from val_minutes vm
) m on m.code_stas = s.code_stas and m.rnk = 1;
```

Comment: Actually the `date_val` contains date + hour and then will have no duplicate

Comment: What can I do to join to another table which has a `code_mesure` and a `group` ? I need station from a specific group

Comment: Er, `join another_table t on t.code_mesure = m.code_mesure and t.specificgroup = 123`?

Comment: Or, ... are you sure you must join at all? Or are you merely looking for `where s.code_mesure in (select code_mesure from another_table where specificgroup = 123)`?

Comment: Why should I use one or the other ? I tried both and `where...` seems to return the data I need

Comment: If you have some times could you please go in chat with me for few minutes to help me over my full query ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128912/discussion-between-thorsten-kettner-and-weedoze).

Answer (score 0):

Try `row_number()` instead of rank

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT code_mesure,date_val,m_05,m_10,m_15,m_20,m_25,m_30,
  row_number() over (partition by code_mesure order by date_val desc) as row_num
  FROM VAL_MINUTES) x
INNER JOIN N_STATION st
ON SUBSTR(x.code_mesure,1,4) = st.CODE_STAS
WHERE x.row_num= 1
```

Comment: Same problem, I have multiple times the same station because of the `code_mesure`